# Inserting multiple values to a table using XML

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I need to insert all the `RoleTypeID`s(10,9) in the below XML to a table.
I followed the below method. It only inserts the 0th indexed XML entry. How to solve this issue?

```
DECLARE @ResourcePermissionXML xml = '<ResourcePermission><RoleTypeID>10</RoleTypeID><RoleTypeID>9</RoleTypeID></ResourcePermission>'

DECLARE @ResourcePermissionList AS TABLE(RoleTypeID INT);

INSERT INTO @ResourcePermissionList(RoleTypeID)
   SELECT Entries.value('(RoleTypeID)[1]', 'INT') AS RoleTypeID
   FROM @ResourcePermissionXML.nodes('/ResourcePermission') AS PermissionEntries(Entries)

SELECT * FROM @ResourcePermissionList
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change your `INSERT` statement to this:

```
INSERT INTO @ResourcePermissionList(RoleTypeID)
   SELECT Entries.value('(.)[1]', 'INT') AS RoleTypeID
   FROM @ResourcePermissionXML.nodes('/ResourcePermission/RoleTypeID') AS PermissionEntries(Entries)
```

Basically, change the XPath expression in `.nodes()` so that it returns a list of XML fragements for each `<RoleTypeID>` XML element - then you can "reach into" that XML element and get its value, and since the XPath will return all `<RoleTypeID>` elements, you get all values.